# Are domain paths hidden?

Tags: php

If I place a folder in my root directory and give it a name that is not easily guessable, is it effectively hidden?

```
www.my_domain.com/some_path
```

were

```
some_path equals something like "1Ki9u"
```

I want to use this as sort of a quick way to login.  Inside the folder `1Ki9u` would be some php to login me in to my web-application.

Comment: Strengthen your login and you should not have to obfuscate the url.

Comment: See: [Is including a secret GUID in an URL Security Through Obscurity?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36870/is-including-a-secret-guid-in-an-url-security-through-obscurity)

Comment: This isn't secure. *security by obscurity is no security* As the saying goes. You could create a simple login with a database. that would be far more sucre and relatively simple to implement.

Comment: Nobody answered my simple question.  Multiple rants on security.  SO won't let me delete this.

Comment: @TobiasKun: Really?  http://stackoverflow.com/users/2584727/stack-temp?tab=reputation

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Do you see my `-1` for my downvote i made on Sep 1?

Comment: @TobiasKun: Fair point (I see my own, but not others).  Either way, what's your evidence the OP is the serial downvoter?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Well ok. I assumed it. But right after the comment of stack_temp under h2ooooo's post all were downvoted. Saw this often enough in the past time :(

Comment: I don't think this question was meant to be a discussion about security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

With proper server configuration, it can be hidden pretty efficiently. However, I don't think this is a good idea:

- IP address blocking => reliable in most cases, although it can be spoofed quite easily.
- Browser history. Whoever sits on the same PC as you can find your hidden URL. Or if you need to access the hidden data from a friends / colleagues PC ?
- If long enough, it can't really be brute forced, especially since few people will search for weird URLs on a random site.
- Keyloggers/trojans/viruses aren't uncommon. Granted that this is a security risk for regular logins as well, but a login script probably is a bit more secure.
- User friendliness. I don't actually see the difference in how easy it is to remember a 10+ character folder name, or a password (I will presume you will use an email address for login, that you can't really forget). Also, in case you forget the folder name, there's no easy way to recover it (well, FTP login, but that would defeat the purpose). With a login form you can use reset password.

Overall, if you are **careful enough**, it's highly unlikely that your hidden URL will be discovered, but from my point of view there is no real advantage of doing so. Plus, you will not be as secure as you would be with a regular login script.

If you really want to do this, only do it if you don't have very sensitive information. I mean, if someone gets a hold of a personal project you've been working on, it may not be a tragedy, but getting hold of a text file of all the FTP / cPanel passwords you have may hurt quite badly.

Comment: very reasonable answer, not clouded with conspiracy theories and paranoia...thanks.

Comment: I made a login script specially for this for myself - you can check it out here: https://github.com/predavlad/php-simple-login

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** security. This is no different than changing a password from `password` to `password1`. All it takes is brute force to find your URL (there's several programs that can brute-scan a server for 404 errors for this exact reason).

Use **real** security with a **real** secure login.

If you're incredibly lazy, use something as simple as a long `.htpasswd` usename and password.

Comment: My site does not throw 404 errors when you choose an incorrect path.

Comment: @stack_temp It still wouldn't take any more than a simple "this is the response we get for every page - if it's any different, then obviously it was found".

Comment: What is the differentiation between URL hacking and a password hacking, you failed to mention this.

Comment: Why should he mention it? You did not asked that ... A username/pasword combination sure is safer than a url itself. You could also add an login feature, that the user has to wait 2^n, seconds (where n is the count of failed logins) and stuff like that.

Comment: The question asked if domain paths are hidden, he failed to answer this as well.  The question was not about security.

Comment: @mark_huffington: Define "hidden"!  This answer states that it's accessible via brute-force search, the implication being "no it's not hidden".

Answer (score -1):

This is called "Security through obscurity."  The short answer is NO.  This is not even remotely secure.

Answer (score -1):

When you never link to it and keep your bookmarks and history private, there would be nobody knowing it exists. The longer the name of the directory, the smaller the chance someone to guess (or brute-force) the URL.

Though it's not safe at all to log in using just an URL. Even with a login form you're not completely safe since it's not protected against brute-force (though, a non-dictionary password of more than 12 characters is quite safe).

If you want to be really secure, use a two-factor authorisation where you email a login code to a specified email address when the entered password is correct. Then use that code to login. (example)